# Since adding validation, nothing works

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation

I have a basic BMI calculator i wrote, worked fine. Now in class we're adding validation. We did a basic in class validation, and i thought i understood everything fine. Now when im trying to incorporate the validation process into my BMI calculator, nothing works. Not understanding why, and i have the example in class up, as well as my actual javascript that im writing, i cant see what im doing wrong.

Soooo, here's my JS fiddle, and code. Hope somebody can point me in the right direction.
http://jsfiddle.net/56dcedbu/

HTML -

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>BMI Calc</title>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
        <script src="BMI.js"></script>
        <script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.validate/1.13.0/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

 <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
            <label for="txtAge">Age:</label>
            <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtAge" value="0"/><p id="ageRes"></p>
            <br/>
            <label for="txtMass">Mass in Lbs:</label>
            <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtMass" value="0"/>
            <br/>
            <label for="txtHinch">Height in Inches:</label>
            <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtHinch" value="0"/>
            <br/>
            <input type="button" id="btnCalc" value="Calculate"/>
            <p id="result2">Result</p>
        </form>

</body>
</html>
```

And the JS -

```
// JavaScript Document

$(function () {
    //Identify Variables
    var txtMass, txtHinch, result;
    var isValid = $('#form1').validate().form();
    // attach event listener to the toggle button's click event

    $('#btnCalc').click(function () {

        //Set validator
            $.validator.setDefaults({
            errorElement: "span",
            errorClass: "form_error",
            errorPlacement: function(error,element){
                error.insertAfter(element)
                }
            });
            $.extend($.validator.messages,{
            required: "* Required field"
            });
            //Set Validation perameters
            $("#form1").validate({
            rules: {
                txtAge: {
                    required: true,
                    range: [1, 120],
                    digits: true
                },
                txtMass: {
                        require: true,
                        digits: true
                },
                txtHinch: {
                    requre: true,
                    digits: true
                }
            }
            });


        if (isValid) {

            //Set Age range for form accuracy
            if (txtAge < 16 || txtAage > 80){
            //Output
            $('#ageRes').html('Results may not be accurate at your age')
            } else { (txtAge >= 16 || txtAge <= 80)
            $('#ageRes').html('Results should be accurate considering your age')




            //Equation for BMI
            result = ($('#txtMass').val() / ($('#txtHinch').val() * $('#txtHinch').val())) * 703;}

            //If - Else statement from output of BMI equation

            if (result < 16){
            $('#result2').html('Result: '+result.toFixed(1) + ' you are Severely underweight')
            } else if (result <=18 ){
            $('#result2').html('Result: '+result.toFixed(1) + ' you are underweight')
            } else if (result <=24){
            $('#result2').html('Result: '+result.toFixed(1) + ' you are healthy')
            } else if (result <= 30 ){
            $('#result2').html('Result: '+result.toFixed(1) + ' you are seriously overweight')
            } else if (result <=35 ){
            $('#result2').html('Result: '+result.toFixed(1) + ' you are obese')
            } else if (result <=40 ){
            $('#result2').html('Result: '+result.toFixed(1) + ' you are seriously obese')
            }

            }

    });

});
```

As usual, thank you ahead of time, i always get amazing help here. You guys are a priceless resource.

Comment: you have a typo after you test isValid `if (txtAge < 16 || txtAage > 80)` throws an error `Uncaught ReferenceError: txtAage is not defined` change this to txtAge and it should be fine. TIP : Always check the JavaScript console in the browser for errors

Comment: you can't set `isValid` before any user interaction, logic makes no sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple problems here

```js
// JavaScript Document

$(function () {
    //Identify Variables
    var txtMass, txtHinch, result, txtAge;


    //Set validator
    $.validator.setDefaults({
        errorElement: "span",
        errorClass: "form_error",
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            error.insertAfter(element)
        }
    });
    $.extend($.validator.messages, {
        required: "* Required field"
    });
    //Set Validation perameters
    $("#form1").validate({
        rules: {
            txtAge: {
                required: true,
                range: [1, 120],
                digits: true
            },
            txtMass: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            },
            txtHinch: {
                required: true,
                digits: true
            }
        }
    });

    $('#btnCalc').click(function () {

        var isValid = $('#form1').validate().form();


        if (isValid) {
            txtAge = $('#txtAge').val();

            //Set Age range for form accuracy
            if (txtAge < 16 || txtAge > 80) {
                //Output
                $('#ageRes').html('Results may not be accurate at your age');
                return;
            } else if (txtAge >= 16 || txtAge <= 80) {
                $('#ageRes').html('Results should be accurate considering your age')
            }


            //Equation for BMI
            result = ($('#txtMass').val() / ($('#txtHinch').val() * $('#txtHinch').val())) * 703;

            //If - Else statement from output of BMI equation

            if (result < 16) {
                $('#result2').html('Result: ' + result.toFixed(1) + ' you are Severely underweight')
            } else if (result <= 18) {
                $('#result2').html('Result: ' + result.toFixed(1) + ' you are underweight')
            } else if (result <= 24) {
                $('#result2').html('Result: ' + result.toFixed(1) + ' you are healthy')
            } else if (result <= 30) {
                $('#result2').html('Result: ' + result.toFixed(1) + ' you are seriously overweight')
            } else if (result <= 35) {
                $('#result2').html('Result: ' + result.toFixed(1) + ' you are obese')
            } else if (result <= 40) {
                $('#result2').html('Result: ' + result.toFixed(1) + ' you are seriously obese')
            }
        }

    });
});
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.12.0/additional-methods.js"></script>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post" action="">
  <label for="txtAge">Age:</label>
  <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtAge" name="txtAge" value="0" />
  <p id="ageRes"></p>
  <br/>
  <label for="txtMass">Mass in Lbs:</label>
  <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtMass" name="txtMass" value="0" />
  <br/>
  <label for="txtHinch">Height in Inches:</label>
  <input type="text" class="txtInput" id="txtHinch" name="txtHinch" value="0" />
  <br/>
  <input type="button" id="btnCalc" value="Calculate" />
  <p id="result2">Result</p>
</form>
```